# Send button not displaying in my web page

Tags: facebook, send

I tried with HTML5 as well as XFBML version also but send button not appearing on my webpage.
I used the code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/ for http://www.rakthadanam.com. On the developers.facebook.com it is showing properly but on my site it's not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that´s because you cut it from the Social Plugin. There is just no space for it right next to the like button, you are going to have to make it bigger.

Also, there is "send=false" in the source code, so of course there is no send button at all.